# Turning on hotspot under settings displaces my app UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, user-interface

When I turn on personal hotspot on under My iPhone settings the UI of my iPhone App gets displaced 20 pixels below.

Is there a way I can detect whether the hotspot is turned on or off?

Comment: if possible please post a screenshot. i am not able to visualise this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get several sizes using the following selectors, whenever the hotspot or other notification appears the statusBarFrame will become 40px high.

```
CGRect rect;
rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; // Get screen dimensions
NSLog(@"Bounds: %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; // Get application frame dimensions (basically screen - status bar)
NSLog(@"App Frame: %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

rect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]; // Get status bar frame dimensions
NSLog(@"Statusbar frame: %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
```

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your answer. just wanted to clear one point ,the moment hot spot appears on screen my status bar should remain at its original place coordinates however the Hotspot takes 20 pixels below the status bar ? OR Does the status bar moves 20 pixel upwards to -20 pixel  Please clear.?........Also is there a Bool value through which i can check if a Hotspot is appearing non my screen right now or Not..?  Thanks

Comment: The status bar expands and becomes 20 pixels bigger, the position of the status bar does not change, only the size. There is no bool I think, however you can just check if statusbarframe.size.height>20

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options to deal with this:

- Use the proper auto resizing masks on your views for applications that support versions of iOS before iOS 6 and make sure all your custom views deal with setting up their auto resizing masks properly.
- For applications that support iOS 6+, use auto layout and constraints.
- For applications with a lot of custom drawing or views, override -viewWillLayoutSubviews on the view controller, when appropriate, and/or -layoutSubviews on custom views.